# Use of .on() without direct parent

Tags: jquery

How would I use `.on()` in jQuery for an element that isn't a direct parent?

`.live()` would look like this

```
$('.home_collapsibles').find('.ui-collapsible-heading').live('tap', function (event) {});
```

With elements of

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" class="home_collapsibles ui-collapsible-set" data-theme="c" data-inset="false">    
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-r" data-expanded-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-collapsed">
        <h3 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed"><a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-up-c" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c">
```

Here is my JS Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/jostster/WD6DD/

**EDIT:** This seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/jostster/fNNnJ/, However I want to limit the listener to only in the `.home_collapsibles`

Comment: `.live` would not work in your example. Did you mean `$('.home_collapsibles .ui-collapsible-heading').live('tap', ...)`? Which of these elements are dynamic and which are static? The `.on`  documentation is pretty extensive and describes everything with examples. What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: *Chaining methods is not supported. e.g `$("a").find(".offsite, .external").live( ... );` is not valid and does not work as expected.* -- [tha docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: @nbrooks I posted the above like that because I see box.com uses that exact method on their mobile site and it works.

Comment: @Bot Like I said, straight from the jQuery docs "won't work as expected". Anyway, your code seems to work just fine -- remember that a 'click' in a desktop browser isn't the same as a 'tap' in a mobile browser, so I don't think you can test manually. But in code: http://jsfiddle.net/WD6DD/1/

Comment: @nbrooks I switched the tap to a `click` and `vclick` which works for both mobile and desktop. Still a no go.

Comment: @bot Like I said, it will work for tap...not for click...because the jQuery mobile overrides the click handler. With click, you have to unbind it first, otherwise it will stop propagation -- http://jsfiddle.net/nbrooks/WD6DD/10/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.home_collapsibles').on('tap', '.ui-collapsible-heading', function () {});
```

Comment: This is what I thought but that doesn't work... I even tried throwing it in a ready event.

Comment: @Bot: Then you should provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ example with which we can play around with.

Comment: I edited my OP with the JSFiddle I was using that isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

> Rewriting the .live() method in terms of its successors is
>   straightforward; these are templates for equivalent calls for all
>   three event attachment methods:

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

**For pages still using .live(), this list of version-specific differences may be helpful:**

> Before jQuery 1.7, to stop further handlers from executing after one
>   bound using .live(), the handler must return false. Calling
>   .stopPropagation() will not accomplish this. As of jQuery 1.4 the
>   .live() method supports custom events as well as all JavaScript events
>   that bubble. It also supports certain events that don't bubble,
>   including change, submit, focus and blur. In jQuery 1.3.x only the
>   following JavaScript events could be bound: click, dblclick, keydown,
>   keypress, keyup, mousedown, mousemove, mouseout, mouseover, and
>   mouseup.

From: http://api.jquery.com/live/